# Why activated plugin does not appearing in left side menu bar of WordPress admin area?

Tags: plugins

can anyone help me i am trying to create a plugin for gallery but at the initiating
a problem occurred,when i activate the plugin it activating but problem is that it does not appearing at left menu ,

`this is my code of plugin startup:|`

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:JaissGallery
Plugin URI:WWW.GOOGLE.COM
description: >-Jaiss gallery plugin
Version: 0.1
Author: Mr. Tahrid abbas
Author URI: http://mrtotallyawesome.com
*/

function doctors_gallery(){
    add_menu_page(
    "doctorsGallery",
    "Doctors Gallery",
    "Manage_options",
    "DoctorsGallery",
    "Doc_gallery_view"
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu','doctors_gallery');

function Doc_gallery_view(){
    echo "ghfhgfgh";
}
```

can somebody tell me please what i am missing there ?

Comment: Maybe another read of the [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) explanation and take a good look at the examples.
Be aware that using caps on the wrong places is  a *no go*- also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Menu and Submenu,

[image]

```
function doctors_gallery(){
    add_menu_page(
        __( 'Doctors Gallery', 'textdomain' ),
        'Doctors Gallery',
        'manage_options', //  The capability required for this menu to be displayed to the user.
        'DoctorsGallery',
        'doc_gallery_view'
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'DoctorsGallery',
        __( 'Doctors Submenu Page', 'textdomain' ),
        __( 'Doctors Submenu', 'textdomain' ),
        'manage_options',
        'DoctorsSubGallery',
        'doctor_submenu_callback'
    );

}

add_action( 'admin_menu','doctors_gallery' );

function doc_gallery_view(){
    echo "ghfhgfgh";
}

function doctor_submenu_callback(){
    echo "Sub Menu section";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
function doctors_gallery(){
    add_menu_page(
        __( 'Doctors Gallery', 'textdomain' ),
        'Doctors Gallery',
        'manage_options', //  The capability required for this menu to be displayed to the user.
        'DoctorsGallery',
        'doc_gallery_view'
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu','doctors_gallery' );

function doc_gallery_view(){
    echo "ghfhgfgh";
}
```

Comment: nice catch,thank you so much ,now my plugin is appearing...

Comment: i need your one more help again i want to create a image uploading type gallery ,in next step what can i do please gave me idea or code ,what i can take next step because i am new in plugin development .